# Golang TCP File Transfer Gets Stuck In the Middle

Tags: go

I'm having some file transfer issue over `TCP` in `go`. The file transfer works sometimes and sometimes it gets stuck in the middle. When it gets stuck, it looks like it is expecting data in the communication channel but there is no data and no error as well. Hence it gets stuck indefinitely. To make thing confusing it shows this behavior for same file i.e for same file it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work.

This is how my program works. It'll listen for incoming requests. The requests are in `JSON` format. Based on request type it'll do different operation. I'm posting the code segment related to file transfer.

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    _"io"
    "net"
    "os"
)

const (
    COMMAND_RECEIVE_FILE    = "TRANSFER_FILE"
    COMMAND_EXIT            = "EXIT"

    CONNECTION_TYPE = "tcp"
    CONNECTION_PORT = "3645"
    CONNECTION_HOST = ""
    BUFFER_SIZE     = 1024
)

type Command struct {
    Identifier string `json:"identifier"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Size       int64  `json:"size"`
}

type Result struct {
    Message     string        `json:"message"`
}

func receiveFile(connection net.Conn, fileName string, fileSize int64) Result {
    fmt.Println("Receiving file")
    result := Result{Message: ""}

    file, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        result.Message = "Error opening file: " + fileName
        return result
    }

    defer file.Close()

    fileBuffer := make([]byte, BUFFER_SIZE)
    bytesRead := int64(0)
    count := 0
    for {
        if fileSize-bytesRead < int64(BUFFER_SIZE) {
            fileBuffer = make([]byte, fileSize-bytesRead)
        }

        fmt.Println("Reading ", BUFFER_SIZE, " bytes of data")
        n, err := connection.Read(fileBuffer)
        count++
        fmt.Println("Completed reading", n, " bytes of data, count=", count)
        file.Write(fileBuffer[0:n])
        bytesRead += int64(n)

        if err != nil {
            result.Message = "File transfer incomplete"
            break
        }

        if bytesRead >= fileSize {
            result.Message = "File transfer complete"
            break
        }
    }

    file.Chmod(0777)

    return result
}

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen(CONNECTION_TYPE, CONNECTION_HOST + ":"+CONNECTION_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error opening a tcp connection")
    }

    for {
        fmt.Println("waiting for new connection")
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {

        } else {
            var commandStr string
            reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

            var exitStatus = 1
            for exitStatus == 1 {
                fmt.Println("Waiting for new command: ")
                line,_,err := reader.ReadLine()
                if err != nil {
                    conn.Close()
                    exitStatus = 0
                    break
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("Size read :", len(line))
                }
                commandStr = string(line)
                fmt.Println("CommandStr: ", commandStr)


                var msg Command
                err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(commandStr), &msg)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Error")
                    conn.Close()
                    break
                }

                result := Result{}
                fmt.Println("Received new command: ", msg.Identifier)
                switch msg.Identifier {

                case COMMAND_RECEIVE_FILE:
                    result = receiveFile(conn, msg.Name, msg.Size)

                case COMMAND_EXIT:
                    exitStatus = 0
                    conn.Close()
                default:
                    result = Result{Message: "Unrecognized command"}
                }

                out, _ := json.Marshal(result)
                fmt.Fprint(conn, string(out)+"\n")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
    _"time"
)

const (
    COMMAND_TRANSFER_FILE   = "TRANSFER_FILE"
    COMMAND_EXIT            = "EXIT"

    CONNECTION_TYPE = "tcp"
    CONNECTION_PORT = "3645"
    CONNECTION_HOST = ""
)

type Command struct {
    Identifier string `json:"identifier"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Size       int64  `json:"size"`
}

type Result struct {
    Message     string        `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial(CONNECTION_TYPE, CONNECTION_HOST + ":" + CONNECTION_PORT)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(conn)
    com := Command{}

    sourceFileName := ""
    destinationFileName := ""
    for {
        com = Command{}
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        identifier, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        com.Identifier = strings.TrimSpace(identifier)

        switch com.Identifier {
        case COMMAND_TRANSFER_FILE:
            fmt.Print("Source file name:")
            sourceFileName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            sourceFileName = strings.TrimSpace(sourceFileName)

            fmt.Print("Destination file name:")
            destinationFileName, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
            com.Name = strings.TrimSpace(destinationFileName)

            file, err := os.Open(sourceFileName)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            defer file.Close()

            fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
            fileSize := fileInfo.Size()
            com.Size = fileSize

        case COMMAND_EXIT:
            conn.Close()
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        out, _ := json.Marshal(com)
        conn.Write([]byte(string(out) + "\n"))

        if strings.Compare(com.Identifier, COMMAND_TRANSFER_FILE) == 0 {
            file, err := os.Open(sourceFileName)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            defer file.Close()

            n, err := io.Copy(conn, file)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(n, "bytes sent")
        }

        var msg Result
        err := decoder.Decode(&msg)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

I tested it on both Linux and Windows and it shows same behavior on both system. The only thing I can think of is that the sender is faster than the receiver even though I'm running it on the same machine. If that is the case, what will be a best practice to solve it other than the handshaking mechanism.

Comment: it worked for me: 1st i started the server code, then the client code, then i typed TRANSFER_FILE in the client stdin, then i entered a 64MB filename name and a destination name and it was copied as expected.

Comment: did you try to transfer same file continuously for several times?

Comment: yep https://gist.github.com/gonzaloserrano/1c4bfda42bf8ddfb87cedc62c91b2878

Comment: that is very strange behavior. for me it gets stuck sometime at the very first try and sometimes after several successful try. I don't know if it has anything to do with the file size.

Comment: Where exactly in the code is it blocked for you?

Comment: In server.go receiveFile() function. Line - n, err := connection.Read(fileBuffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't wrap the `net.Conn` in a `bufio.Reader`, then continue to use the `net.Conn`. The reason your function is blocked is because you left data buffered in the `reader`, so you won't ever reach the desired message size.

You need to pass the `reader` to the `receiveFile` function in order to not lose the buffered data.

You are also ignoring the `isPrefix` return value from `ReadLine`. I would follow the documentation and use `ReadBytes` instead if you're not going to handle all cases from that method.